# Dart Abstract class of Generic Type with Named Constructor

Tags: dart

I am attempting to construct an abstract class that requires a named constructor in Dart. Given some Map (m), this generic type must be able instantiate itself.

The Dart compiler is throwing `T.fromJson -> Invalid constructor name.`

My attempt at coding this:

```dart
abstract class JsonMap<T> {
  Map toJson();
  T.fromJson(Map m);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with the same concept (in the same place ... API parsing :)) ) and I didn't found a proper solution.

But maybe you can use something this thing I found while checking block pattern this (I am not using it for my model part):

```
abstract class SomeBase {
  void load();
}

class Provider<T extends SomeBase> extends InheritedWidget {
  final T something;

  Provider({
    Key key,
    @required this.something,
  }): super(key: key);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_) {
    return true;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

  static T of<T extends SomeBase>(BuildContext context){
    final type = _typeOf<Provider<T>>();
    Provider<T> provider = context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type);
    return provider.something;
  }
}
```

OR just use this without encapsulating it in an inherited widget and provide the already initialised objects (like user or whatever you are parsing) that just load the values from the JSON provided.

Comment: Interesting! I am still new to Dart. Mind explaining this class a bit?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a class named `JsonMap` that is parameterized on type `T`.  `T` is not the name of your class, so `T.fromJson` is not a valid named constructor for `JsonMap`.

If you want `JsonMap` to have a named constructor, it should be `JsonMap.fromJson(Map m)`.

Comment: I don't want `JsonMap` to have a named constructor, I want the concrete class that extends `JsonMap` to be forced to implement a named constructor by that name.

Comment: @BajaBob This is still not clear.  Do you mean you expect `JsonMap` to have a derived class (i.e. `class Derived<T> extends JsonMap<T> { Derived.fromJson(Map m) { ... }}` or you want `T` to have a named constructor? (Or are you doing a CRTP thing `T` is the derived type?) You also should clarify this in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but off the top of my head, you should write your code like so:

```
abstract class JsonMap<T> {
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
  T fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> m);
}
```

The dot makes `fromJson(Map m)` a constructor of type T, or a static function belonging to type T. Without the dot, it is a function belonging to the abstract class JsonMap, returning type T. Specifying the map type is good practice if you know what it will be (like with json).